# Future.filter runtime exception without any if-guards

Tags: scala, exception, future

I'm sporadically getting `util.NoSuchElementException: Future.filter predicate is not satisfied` exceptions.

My understanding from other questions is that this appears with `if guards` in `for comprehensions`. I extensively use `for comprehensions` but I can't find any conditions. I do however make some assignments.

```scala
for {
  foo <- Future{0}
  bar = foo + 1
} yield bar
```

However, my understanding is that this should be fine.

I'm struggling to find the source of the runtime exception. Are there other cases where `Future.filter` would be called, besides `if guards`? Any other ideas of what I should be looking for?

**Edit:**

Could this be caused by pattern matching, like

```scala
for {
  foo <- Future{0 -> 1}
  (bar, _) <- foo
} yield bar + 1
```

**Edit2:**

I'm guessing the above is fine but this might cause a RTE?

```scala
for {
  (bar, _) <- Future{0 -> 1}
} yield bar + 1
```

Comment: `(bar, _) <- Future{0 -> 1}` _shouldn't_ cause RTE, but if you used an ADT like Option, and matched on `Some(value)` it could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.filter` and `.withFilter` (lazy version preferred by for-comprehension) remove from your  `F[_]` values that don't fulfill the predicate:

- with List it removed values from the List and returns a List with those values removed
- with Option it turns Some to None if predicate is not fulfilled
- with Try - it's similar to Option but Success is treated like Some, and Failure like None - however Failure cannot be empty, and that's why it puts Exception there
- Future is asynchronous Try.

For that reason `.withFilter(condition)` is basically lazy version of

```
.flatMap { value =>
  if (condition(value)) => Future.successful(value)
  else Future.failed(new util.NoSuchElementException("Future.filter predicate is not satisfied"))
}
```

You will get that for every case that call `.withFilter` on Future underneath. With for comprehension that would be:

- direct call of `.withFilter`
- usage of if clause
- usage of pattern matching

```
for {
  f <- future.withFilter(cond1) // this might raise exception
  g <- makeFuture(f) if cond2 // this might raise
  (head, tail) <- makeFutureList(g) // this might raise
} yield
```

To avoid it (in Future or other IO monads)

- don't call withFilter manually
- instead of if use if-else:

```
for {
  value <- future
  success <- if (cond(value)) Future.successful(value)
             else Future.failed(yourOwnError) // handle however you like
} yield success
```

You can also use better monadic for to avoid using `.withFilter` on pattern matching which cannot fail (though if they can fail you would still get exception, so it's not a solution, but still nice a way of getting rid of unwanted .withFilter).

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP is asking why they get the exception when they are not using guards...

Comment: @TIm, actually it might. I use pattern matching, see my updated question

Comment: If you have `(a, b) <- Future(1 -> 2)` it shouldn't as it would always match. But `Some(value) <- Future(Option(someInt).filter(_ > 0))` would result in RTE if that `Option` was `None`. Check if there is something like that, or use better-monadic-for to check if you get pattern matching exception instead of `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Thanks. Can't see any atm but I'll do some better logging to aid in finding the culprit. There's a `(classA, classB) <- Try{Await.result(Future{classA -> classB}, 1 minute)}`

Comment: I located the offending code where I call two futures
```val f3 = for { a <- f1, b <- f2 } yield a -> b ; 
Try { Await.result(f3, ...) }

```
and f2 completes with a `Success(null)` which appears to cause the `withFilter` RTE as the `withFilter` RTE is gone when I make the future return `Option(B)`. I will accept your answer but bonus points if you can explain why this would cause the `withFilter` RTE :)

Comment: If you had `(something, _) <- future` as in your question and it completed with `Success(null)`, then you would pattern match `null` against a tuple which has to fail and produce failed `.withFilter` which ends up with error you saw.