# Scala for comprehension responding Future.filter predicate is not satisfied

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I got the followin code

```scala
val obj1Seq: Future[Seq[Object1]] = /* call function returning Future[Seq[Object1]] */
val obj2Seq: Future[Seq[Object2]] = /* call function returning Future[Seq[Object2]] */
for {
  objects1 <- obj1Seq
  objects2 <- obj2Seq if (objects1.map(_.id) == objects2.map(_.relateObjId))
} yield {
  objects2
}
```

With this I want to get all the `Object2` that the `relatedObjId` match the same `id` from the `objects1` list

My problem is that I keep getting the error `Future.filter predicate is not satisfied` I have read few other questions here ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869624/scala-future-with-filter-in-for-comprehension), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808640/for-expression-with-an-if-filter-causes-an-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339979/future-filter-runtime-exception-without-any-if-guards)) and tried to adapt those solutions to my problem but I don't  get to solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve my problem

```scala
val result: Future[Seq[Object2]] = for {
  objects1 <- obj1Seq
  objects2 <- obj2Seq
} yield {
  for {
    obj1 <- objects1
    obj2 <- objects2 if obj1.id == obj2.relatedObjId
  } yield {
    obj2
  }
}
```

One of the things that made me uneasy with this problem is that the function that does this operation I only call it when I know that it will not return an empty list.
Unfortunately I don't quite understand why and haven't had time to investigate further, if anyone has any idea how this works feel free to comment on this answer, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The error you get is expected if the predicate (the sequence comparison) is not satisfied. I.e. you get a `Future.failed` with the said exception.

That's because `Future#withFilter` (which is called by the `if` in the for-comprehension) works like that. See [scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/concurrent/Future.html#filter(p:T=%3EBoolean)(implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext):scala.concurrent.Future%5BT%5D).

---

If I understand your need, your rather want something like this which always give a successful result (if both initial futures are successful):

```scala
val result: Future[Seq[Objects]] = for {
  objects1 <- obj1Seq
  objects2 <- obj2Seq
} yield {
  if (someCondition(objects1, objects2)) {
    // Some logic to get the desired results
    ???
  } else {
    Seq.empty
  }
}
```